# Is the problem that determines whenever the word member $\in$ L(M) decidable or not?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, decision-problem

Given a Turing machine M on alphabet {m,e,b,r} we're asked to determine if member $\in$ L(M).
You must realize that M is not one specific machine and can be any turing Machine with the same alphabet.
My goal is to determine whenever this problem is decidable or not.

My idea was to use mapping reducibility. The goal was to see if we can translate all problems from $A_{TM}$ which is known to be undecidable into our current problem. This would make our current problem undecidable by contagion. However I'm struggling in doing so because I'm not sure if it's possible. $A_{TM}$ is defined as a Turing machine M that accepts the word w.

Any help to get unstuck would be appreciated.

Comment: A small warning: If you frequently delete questions when they are downvoted or commented on (e.g., maybe you are deleting the question, revising it, and re-asking the improved/revised version as a new question), you might risk running into a question ban.  In those circumstances it might be better to revise the question to improve it and address the feedback, rather than deleting it.  I don't fully understand the mechanics behind the question ban or what exactly can trigger it, but I believe that self-deleted downvoted questions can contribute, so I wanted to let you know in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it like this:

Reduction from $A_{TM}$: Given TM $A$ und word $w$.

Use that to define a new machine $A'$ that works as follows:

1. Run like $A$ on input $w$
2. If $A$ rejects $w$, go into eternal loop.
3. If $A$ accepts, delete the band content and write "member"

Comment: thank you for the answer!